# update query processing

Tags: sql, jsp, sql-update

please provide the solution

i am trying to fire the following update query as-

```
update_query="UPDATE demo.shop SET S_NO=1 , NAME='df' , VENDOR='xyz' , VERSION='10.10' ,INSTALL_PATH='/bin' , LICENSE='null' , SERVER_NAME='serv' WHERE NAME='name1' AND VERSION='10.10' ";

statement.executeUpdate(update_query);
```

all fields are varchar2 type except S_NO field

but the browser keeps on background proceesing (i mean cursor keep on rolling) but the update operation is not successful...even cursor does not come back to ready mode...it keeps on rolling

Comment: debug and find where the execution gets slow.

Comment: @divyabharathi That's never be an good answer.

Comment: @Baadshah: I mean not only because of this update query the application will get slower... there will be many more reasons behind.. debugging may find the root cause of why an update is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any process is locking the write to the database, table or row. If you have uncomitted transactions you are not able to change those datas.

Check:

1. Toad or any other Database-Manager for uncommitted transactions.
2. Any of your Development-systems if they are debugging inside of a transaction
3. Check using "show processlist" for Users/Hosts for changes to the row/table/db

Regards